# Open Outlook .msg like a text file in Python?

Tags: python, email, encoding

I want to treat Outlook `.msg` file as string and check if a substring exists in it.

So I thought importing `win32` library, which is suggested in similar SO threads, would be an overkill.

Instead, I tried to just open the file the same way as a .txt file:

```
file_path= 'O:\\MAP\\177926 Delete comiitted position.msg'

mail = open(file_path)
mail_contents = mail.read()
print(mail_contents)
```

However, I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 870: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there any decoding I can specify to make it work?

I have also tried

```
mail = open(file_path, encoding='utf-8')
```

which returns

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: try `mail = open(file_path, encoding='utf-8')`, not `utf`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried, just my mistake in the question, updated now.

Comment: Then, try `mail = open(file_path, encoding='Latin-1')`. The error will probably go away, but make sure to output is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you face these type of issues, it is good pratice to try the Python `Latin-1` encoding.

```
mail = open(file_path, encoding='Latin-1')
```

We often confound the Windows `cp1252` encoding with the actual Python's `Latin-1`. Indeed, the latter maps all possible byte values to the first 256 Unicode code points.

See [this](https://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html#files-in-an-ascii-compatible-encoding-best-effort-is-acceptable) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're willing to do a lot of work, you really should use a library for this.

First, a `.msg` file is a binary file, so the contents should not be read in as a string. A string is usually terminated with a `null byte`, and binary files can have a lot of those inside, which could mean you're not looking at all the data (might depend on the implementation).

Also, the `.msg` file can have plain ascii and/or unicode in different parts/blocks of the file, so it would be really hard to treat this as one string to search for a substring.

As an alternative you could save the mails as `.eml` (i.e. the plain text version of an e-mail), but there would still be some problems to overcome in order to search for a specific text:

- All data in an [e-mail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) are lower ascii (1-127) which means special characters have to be encoded to lower ascii bytes. There are several different encodings for headers (for example 'Subject'), body, attachment.
- Body text: can be plain text or hml (or both). Lines and words can be split because there is a maximum line length. Different encodings can be used, even `base64` in which you would never find the text you're looking for.
- A lot more would have to be done to properly decode everything, but this should give you an idea of the work you would have to do in order to find the text you're looking for.